# It is possible to keep blueberry bushes as a house plant?

Tags: indoors, shrubs, fruits

I'll be going moving soon from my house to an apartment, and most likely a studio at that, so I was wondering if it was possible to grow lowbrush blueberry bushes as a houseplant and expect it to bear fruit

Comment: I'd have to suspect that either buying berries or traveling to a site where you can pick would be far more cost-effective for an apartment dweller - plants without adequate light fruit poorly, if at all, and adequate light is a LOT of light compared to most apartments. Plenty of outside locations fruit poorly due to excess shade.

Comment: And furthermore they normally recommend that you have two blueberry plants to get more fruit.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to grow them indoors, provided you can stand the pot somewhere that gets 6 hours of sunlight a day, which can be hard to ensure, depending where you live. The other difficulty is pollination, because insects carry out this duty, so you'd need to hand pollinate in order to get fruit. Ericaceous (acid) potting mix is essential,as well as choosing a smaller variety, not least because some reach a fair height, and that's not desirable indoors. More info here http://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-grow-blueberries-houseplant-57717.html

Comment: What about house flies acting as pollinators? http://theseedsofscience.com/2013/06/16/87/

Comment: What about 'em?! I nearly made an ironic  reference to a roomful  of flies, but frankly, if you're living in a studio flat, I very much doubt that the presence of several flies over a period of time would be welcomed by the human resident. I'd find even one offensive in a combined living/sleeping space personally...

Comment: Clearly you have better control of insects than I do.  I'm always zapping flies and feeding them to my fish during summer. I  think they like all the flowers in the garden.

Comment: Although blueberries do have perfect flowers (with pollen and the ability to fruit in each flower), they're still said to need insects to pollinate them according to this: http://www.newenglandvfc.org/pdf_proceedings/2009/PIiBP.pdf

Comment: @GrahamChiu I rarely get flies in my apartment (window nets doing the job, maybe),  and any that do come in don't last long!

Comment: I was hoping to either hand pollinate them or be able to set them in an open window, provided that I don't wind up living too high up

Comment: Better wait and see where you end up living, so you know whether it's possible - even the level of sunlight required could be difficult, depending on aspect and window size.